# Haxe generics - curly braces as constraint

Tags: generics, haxe

What does the empty curly braces constraint mean?
For example (taken from the [ObjectMap](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/std/haxe/ds/ObjectMap.hx) implementation of Map):

```
extern class ObjectMap < K: { }, V > implements Map.IMap<K,V> {
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A type parameter of `{}` matches any **object**.  This includes class instances, anonymous objects etc, but excludes Ints, Floats, Bools and other basic types.

A type parameter of `Dynamic` on the other hand matches both objects and ints, floats, bools etc.

(Please note: as @back2dos pointed out, a String counts as a class instance, so will satisfy the type constraint `{}`)

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I searched through the official Haxe documentation but was unable to find any mention of {}. I wonder why it isn't named -  K:Object would be much more intuitive than K:{}.

Comment: Side note: Unfortunately `{}` includes strings, since they are in fact class instances.

Comment: @LukaŠverko I honestly couldn't find it in the manual either, so not sure where I learned this... I might make a suggestion that it gets included in the next version of the manual